# What to do with almost-link-only answers?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, link-only-answers

I recently failed [this first-posts audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/8666518), with review ban as a consequence. In downvoted, as it looks to me a link only answer.

Full post:

> The easiest way, if you have fonts that are not embedded, is using the preflight function of Adobe Acrobat Pro. See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SdIVy2D4b4

Arguably, this post has a bit more than a link only (suggestion to use library/software).

What is your opinion? Should I have upvoted/clicked 'Looks OK'? And what should be done in general with this type of short answers?

Comment: It is the highest voted answer on the question, outscoring the accepted answer.  How can you possibly miss that?   Are you paying attention?   That's what the audit tests.  Don't know what "preflight" might mean?  Watch the video :)

Comment: @HansPassant In the audit the post score is not visible. I could open every review question and check the score to 'bypass' the audits, but that kind of defeats the whole purpose imo. I had to review this post, saw a low quality post in my eyes, and decided to downvote. I don't think there is a need to open the original question to check any votes. The first-posts reviews don't ask: "Is this a highly upvoted answer?" but "Is this a good quality post from a person who just joined SO?" At least that's how I treat the reviews.

Comment: That's what I do.  An answer never lives in a vacuum, a short link-only answer is worth its weight in gold if it is the only answer.  And hey, I never failed an audit yet.  If you don't want to do the work then just don't do it, nobody forces you.

Comment: @HansPassant I ask a question here on meta to learn if I did the correct thing or not, and to discuss my failed audit. If I didn't want to review, I wouldn't review, and I would definitely not come here and ask about it. Congratulations for never failing an audit.

Answer (score 4):

I would probably have made the same choice as you given that it is a link to a youtube video and to me links to youtube videos are the worst kind of link-only answers. As such it is a good audit question, you have to really pay attention when reviewing it.

Because the link is only secondary. The actual answer is "The easiest way, if you have fonts that are not embedded, is using the preflight function of Adobe Acrobat Pro." That's a rather short answer that implies little more than "google adobe acrobat preflight" and it looks like it is not correct in the context of the question at all, but it is an answer nonetheless.

Comment: I can agree that it is not a link-only answer, but I still don't think it is a good audit. If it is an answer nonetheless, it can still be a low quality one, which implies I have a right to downvote (I didn't vote to close).

Comment: Well there my knowledge of reviewing fails me. Does downvoting in review mean the same thing as downvoting the answer directly on the site?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. The literal message I got after failing this review: STOP! Look and Listen

This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. Your review was inappropriate. This was a high quality post and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even upvoting.

Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately - but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.

Comment: Fair enough. But as you will see when you do a meta search for "audit", that is the general case. I don't think that anything is going to be done to this automated system (a necessary evil) just because you were caught by it when dozens if not hundreds of other people just had to suck it up ;)